# What does the "SQLite3::SQLException: near ".": syntax error" mean?

Tags: sql

I'm writing an ORM (object relational model) and I've been stuck on this error message for a while now. I did narrow it down to the update and the save method (I have a feeling that the error most likely is in the update method specifically), but I can't figure out where the syntax error is happening.

Here is the error message:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near ".": syntax error
from /Users/karenlee/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:147:in `initialize'
```

And here is my ORM:

```
require_relative 'questions_database'

class User
  attr_reader :id
  attr_accessor :fname, :lname

  # displays all users
  def self.all
    users = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    users.map { | user_info | User.new(user_info) }
  end

  # finds a user by their primary id
  def self.find_by_id(id)
    found_user = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, id: id)
      SELECT
        users.*
      FROM
        users
      WHERE
        users.id = :id
    SQL
    found_user.nil? ? nil : User.new(found_user.first)
  end

  # finds a user by their first and last name
  def self.find_by_name(fname, lname)
    name = {fname: fname, lname: lname}
    found_user = QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, name)
      SELECT
        users.*
      FROM
        users
      WHERE
        users.fname = :fname AND users.lname = :lname
    SQL
    found_user.nil? ? nil : User.new(found_user.first)
  end

  # creates a new user instance
  def initialize(options)
    @id, @fname, @lname = options.values_at('id', 'fname', 'lname')
  end

  # saves the user into the database (or updates when needed)
  def save
    if self.id
      update
    else  
      create
    end
  end

  private
  # helper method to update the database
  def update
    values = {id: id, fname: fname, lname: lname}
    QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, values)
      UPDATE
        users
      SET
        users.fname = :fname, users.lname = :lname
      WHERE
        users.id = :id
    SQL
  end

  # helper method to create a row in the database
  def create
    name = {fname: fname, lname: lname}
    QuestionsDatabase.instance.execute(<<-SQL, name)
      INSERT INTO
        users (fname, lname)
      VALUES
        (:fname, :lname)
    SQL
    self.id = QuestionsDatabase.instance.last_insert_row_id
  end
end
```

Here's the QuestionsDatabase class if you need it:

```
require 'sqlite3'
require 'singleton'

class QuestionsDatabase < SQLite3::Database
    include Singleton  

    def initialize
      super('questions.db')
      self.type_translation = true
      self.results_as_hash = true
    end
end
```

**UPDATE:**

I've found where my error was! It turned out that I should have just been saying `fname = :fname, lname = :lname` instead of saying `users.fname = :fname, users.lname = :lname`. But I'm still unsure as to why this is. It seems like the update statement doesn't like it when I don't use aliases, but some more explanation on this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It turned out that I should have just been saying fname = :fname, lname = :lname instead of saying users.fname = :fname, users.lname = :lname. But I'm still unsure as to why this is.

If you look at the [`UPDATE` syntax diagrams](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) you'll see it just takes plain column names. There's no need to specify the table name because you can only update a single table at a time; no room for ambiguity like in a `SELECT`. Therefore the parser rules don't support an optional table name component there.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that aliases are only available in the FROM clause. So if I were to use aliases in the UPDATE statement, it would have to be structured differently; I'd have to use a FROM clause. See this link for more info on restructuring!

https://sqlstudies.com/2013/09/16/dba-myths-you-cant-use-an-alias-in-an-update-statement/